# Data Augmentation on tf.dataset.Dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

In order to use Google Colabs TPUs I need a `tf.dataset.Dataset`. How can I then use Data Augmentation on such a dataset?

More specifically, my code so far is:

```
def get_dataset(batch_size=200):
  datasets, info = tfds.load(name='mnist', with_info=True, as_supervised=True,
                             try_gcs=True)
  mnist_train, mnist_test = datasets['train'], datasets['test']

  def scale(image, label):
    image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32)
    image /= 255.0

    label = tf.one_hot(label,10)

    return image, label

  train_dataset = mnist_train.map(scale).shuffle(10000).batch(batch_size)
  test_dataset = mnist_test.map(scale).batch(batch_size)

  return train_dataset, test_dataset
```

Which is fed into this:

```
# TPU Strategy ...
with strategy.scope():
  model = create_model()
  model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy",
                optimizer="adam",
                metrics=["acc"])

train_dataset, test_dataset = get_dataset()

model.fit(train_dataset,
          epochs=20,
          verbose=1,
          validation_data=test_dataset)
```

So, how can I use here Data Augmentation here?
As far as I know, I can't use the tf.keras ImageDataGenerator, right?

I've tried the following and it didn't work.

```
data_generator = ...

model.fit_generator(data_generator.flow(train_dataset, batch_size=32),
                    steps_per_epoch=len(train_dataset) / 32, epochs=20)
```

Not surprising, since, usually, train_x and train_y are fed as two arguments to the flow function, not "packed" into one `tf.dataset.Dataset`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [tf.image](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image) functions. The `tf.image` module contains various functions for image processing.

**For example:**

You can add below functionality in your function `def get_dataset`.

- convert each image to `tf.float64` in the `0-1` range.
- `cache()` results as those can be re-used after each `repeat`
- randomly flip left_to_right each image using `random_flip_left_right`.
- randomly change contrast of image using `random_contrast`.
- Number of images increased by twice by `repeat` which repeat all the steps.

**Code -**

```
mnist_train = mnist_train.map(
    lambda image, label: (tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, tf.float32), label)
).cache(
).map(
    lambda image, label: (tf.image.random_flip_left_right(image), label)
).map(
    lambda image, label: (tf.image.random_contrast(image, lower=0.0, upper=1.0), label)
).shuffle(
    1000
).
batch(
    batch_size
).repeat(2)
```

Similarly you can use other functionalities like `random_flip_up_down`, `random_crop` functions to Randomly flips an image vertically (upside down) and Randomly crop a tensor to a given size respectively.

---

Your `get_dataset` function will look like below -

```
def get_dataset(batch_size=200):
  datasets, info = tfds.load(name='mnist', with_info=True, as_supervised=True,
                             try_gcs=True)
  mnist_train, mnist_test = datasets['train'], datasets['test']

  train_dataset = mnist_train.map(
               lambda image, label: (tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, tf.float32),label)
              ).cache(
              ).map(
                    lambda image, label: (tf.image.random_flip_left_right(image), label)
              ).map(
                    lambda image, label: (tf.image.random_contrast(image, lower=0.0, upper=1.0), label)
              ).shuffle(
                    1000
              ).batch(
                    batch_size
              ).repeat(2)

  test_dataset = mnist_test.map(scale).batch(batch_size)

  return train_dataset, test_dataset
```

Adding the link suggested by @Andrew H that gives end-to-end example on [data augmentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/data_augmentation#augment_a_dataset_and_train_a_model_with_it) that also uses `mnist` dataset.

Hope this answers your question. Happy Learning.

Comment: Informative answer, though I personally find the large amounts of lambdas tough to parse. Each of the mappings could be placed into one larger mapping, similar to here:
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/data_augmentation#augment_a_dataset_and_train_a_model_with_it

Comment: @Andrew H - Thank You for suggesting the link, its very informative. Have added it in the answers.

Comment: @Lukas Nießen - Hope we have answered your question. Can you please accept and upvote the answer if you are satisfied with the answer.

Comment: Why not `repeat` first, and then `map`? If so, we can get twice larger dataset with different data instead of the same data repeated twice.